# line separator with in 2 columns div

Tags: html, css

i want to put line separator in html div like this : a Black line Z shape "mirror image" as you see below , i tried to set last left side div and first right side div border but i am not able think that how could i draw vertical line, **with very smart way to use CSS**

[image]

i tried this :-

```
<div id="wrap">
        <div>
            <div class="left_col">Industry:</div>
            <div class="right_col" style="border-Top: 1px solid black">Insurance</div>
        </div>
        <div >
            <div class="left_col" >Co. Size:</div>
            <div class="right_col">201 - 500 Employees</div>
        </div>
        <div >
            <div class="left_col">Working Hours:</div>
            <div class="right_col">Regular hours, Mondays-Fridays</div>
        </div>
        <div >
            <div class="left_col">Benefits:</div>
            <div class="right_col">Medical, Education support, Loans, Dental</div>
        </div>
        <div >
            <div class="left_col" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">Spoken Language:</div>
            <div class="right_col">English</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**example** is here : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6ypc/)

Comment: Only a suggestion: don't use in-line css :)

Comment: either me , i dont want to use inline css :( , that's why i asked here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two dis to wrap the left and right columns

And here is the css for your requirement

```
 #wrap{margin:10px;}
.left{
   width:50%; display:table-cell;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
    border-right: 1px solid black; 
    padding:15px
}
.right{
    display:table-cell;
    border-top: 1px solid black; 
    vertical-align:top;  width:50%;
    padding:15px
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VgGDp/7/)**

Comment: Thanks, but i got this result when i clicked on demo : http://postimage.org/image/fa2rq4mjb/ , and this is not what i wanted

Comment: @ALAN Use table-cell instead of inline-bloc. Check the updated answer